# Mocking sqlobject function call for test db

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, sqlobject

I am trying to mock `sqlbuilder.func` for test cases with pytest

I successfully mocked `sqlbuilder.func.TO_BASE64` with correct output but when I tried mocking `sqlbuilder.func.FROM_UNIXTIME` I didn't get any error but the resulted output is incorrect with the generated query. Below is the minimal working example of the problem.

**models.py**

```py
from sqlobject import (
    sqlbuilder,
    sqlhub,
    SQLObject,
    StringCol,
    BLOBCol,
    TimestampCol,
)

class Store(SQLObject):
    name = StringCol()
    sample = BLOBCol()
    createdAt = TimestampCol()

DATE_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d"
def retrieve(name):
    query = sqlbuilder.Select([
            sqlbuilder.func.TO_BASE64(Store.q.sample),
        ],
        sqlbuilder.AND(
            Store.q.name == name,
            sqlbuilder.func.FROM_UNIXTIME(Store.q.createdAt, DATE_FORMAT) >= sqlbuilder.func.FROM_UNIXTIME("2018-10-12", DATE_FORMAT)
        )
    )

    connection = sqlhub.getConnection()
    query = connection.sqlrepr(query)
    print(query)
    queryResult = connection.queryAll(query)
    return queryResult
```

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest

from models import Store
from sqlobject import sqlhub
from sqlobject.sqlite import sqliteconnection

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="session")
def sqlite_db_session(tmpdir_factory):
    file = tmpdir_factory.mktemp("db").join("sqlite.db")
    conn = sqliteconnection.SQLiteConnection(str(file))
    sqlhub.processConnection = conn
    init_tables()
    yield conn
    conn.close()

def init_tables():
    Store.createTable(ifNotExists=True)
```

**test_ex1.py**

```
import pytest

from sqlobject import sqlbuilder
from models import retrieve

try:
    import mock
    from mock import MagicMock
except ImportError:
    from unittest import mock
    from unittest.mock import MagicMock

def TO_BASE64(x):
    return x

def FROM_UNIXTIME(x, y):
    return 'strftime("%Y%m%d", datetime({},"unixepoch", "localtime"))'.format(x)

# @mock.patch("sqlobject.sqlbuilder.func.TO_BASE64")
# @mock.patch("sqlobject.sqlbuilder.func.TO_BASE64", MagicMock(side_effect=lambda x: x))
# @mock.patch("sqlobject.sqlbuilder.func.TO_BASE64", new_callable=MagicMock(side_effect=lambda x: x))
@mock.patch("sqlobject.sqlbuilder.func.TO_BASE64", TO_BASE64)
@mock.patch("sqlobject.sqlbuilder.func.FROM_UNIXTIME", FROM_UNIXTIME)
def test_retrieve():
    result = retrieve('Some')
    assert result == []
```

**Current SQL:**

```sql
SELECT store.sample FROM store WHERE (((store.name) = ('Some')) AND (1))
```

**Expected SQL:**

```sql
SELECT
  store.sample
FROM 
  store
WHERE
  store.name = 'Some'
AND
  strftime(
    '%Y%m%d',
    datetime(store.created_at, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')
  ) >= strftime(
    '%Y%m%d',
    datetime('2018-10-12', 'unixepoch', 'localtime')
  )
```

**Edit Example**

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python

from sqlobject import *

__connection__ = "sqlite:/:memory:?debug=1&debugOutput=1"

try:
    import mock
    from mock import MagicMock
except ImportError:
    from unittest import mock
    from unittest.mock import MagicMock

class Store(SQLObject):
    name = StringCol()
    sample = BLOBCol()
    createdAt = TimestampCol()

Store.createTable()

DATE_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d"
def retrieve(name):
    query = sqlbuilder.Select([
            sqlbuilder.func.TO_BASE64(Store.q.sample),
        ],
        sqlbuilder.AND(
            Store.q.name == name,
            sqlbuilder.func.FROM_UNIXTIME(Store.q.createdAt, DATE_FORMAT) >= sqlbuilder.func.FROM_UNIXTIME("2018-10-12", DATE_FORMAT)
        )
    )

    connection = Store._connection
    query = connection.sqlrepr(query)
    queryResult = connection.queryAll(query)
    return queryResult


def TO_BASE64(x):
    return x

def FROM_UNIXTIME(x, y):
    return 'strftime("%Y%m%d", datetime({},"unixepoch", "localtime"))'.format(x)

for p in [
    mock.patch("sqlobject.sqlbuilder.func.TO_BASE64",TO_BASE64),
    mock.patch("sqlobject.sqlbuilder.func.FROM_UNIXTIME",FROM_UNIXTIME),
]:
    p.start()

retrieve('Some')

mock.patch.stopall()
```

Comment: Could you provide a full test script that doesn't use `pytest`? Just for experimenting… PS. I'm the current maintainer of SQLObject.

Comment: @phd please can you point me how the example would look like

Comment: @phd so i have to share code as in the answer

Comment: [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `sqlbuilder.func` is an `SQLExpression` that passes its attribute (`sqlbuilder.func.datetime`, e.g.) to the SQL backend as a constant (`sqlbuilder.func` actually is an alias for `sqlbuilder.ConstantSpace`). See the docs about [`SQLExpression`](http://sqlobject.org/SQLBuilder.html#sqlexpression), [the FAQ](http://sqlobject.org/FAQ.html#sqlexpression) and the code for [`func`](https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject/blob/master/sqlobject/sqlbuilder.py#L1586-L1587).

When you mock an attribute in `func` namespace it's evaluated by SQLObject and passed to the backend in reduced form. If you want to return a string literal from the mocking function you need to tell SQLObject it's a value that has to be passed to the backend as is, unevaluated. The way to do it is to wrap the literal in `SQLConstant` like this:

```
def FROM_UNIXTIME(x, y):
    return sqlbuilder.SQLConstant('strftime("%Y%m%d", datetime({},"unixepoch", "localtime"))'.format(x))
```

See [`SQLConstant`](https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject/blob/master/sqlobject/sqlbuilder.py#L390-L398).

The entire test script now looks this

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3.7

from sqlobject import *

__connection__ = "sqlite:/:memory:?debug=1&debugOutput=1"

try:
    import mock
    from mock import MagicMock
except ImportError:
    from unittest import mock
    from unittest.mock import MagicMock

class Store(SQLObject):
    name = StringCol()
    sample = BLOBCol()
    createdAt = TimestampCol()

Store.createTable()

DATE_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d"
def retrieve(name):
    query = sqlbuilder.Select([
            sqlbuilder.func.TO_BASE64(Store.q.sample),
        ],
        sqlbuilder.AND(
            Store.q.name == name,
            sqlbuilder.func.FROM_UNIXTIME(Store.q.createdAt, DATE_FORMAT) >= sqlbuilder.func.FROM_UNIXTIME("2018-10-12", DATE_FORMAT)
        )
    )

    connection = Store._connection
    query = connection.sqlrepr(query)
    queryResult = connection.queryAll(query)
    return queryResult


def TO_BASE64(x):
    return x

def FROM_UNIXTIME(x, y):
    return sqlbuilder.SQLConstant('strftime("%Y%m%d", datetime({},"unixepoch", "localtime"))'.format(x))

for p in [
    mock.patch("sqlobject.sqlbuilder.func.TO_BASE64",TO_BASE64),
    mock.patch("sqlobject.sqlbuilder.func.FROM_UNIXTIME",FROM_UNIXTIME),
]:
    p.start()

retrieve('Some')

mock.patch.stopall()
```

The output is:

```
 1/Query   :  CREATE TABLE store (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT,
    sample TEXT,
    created_at TIMESTAMP
)
 1/QueryR  :  CREATE TABLE store (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT,
    sample TEXT,
    created_at TIMESTAMP
)
 2/QueryAll:  SELECT store.sample FROM store WHERE (((store.name) = ('Some')) AND ((strftime("%Y%m%d", datetime(store.created_at,"unixepoch", "localtime"))) >= (strftime("%Y%m%d", datetime(2018-10-12,"unixepoch", "localtime")))))
 2/QueryR  :  SELECT store.sample FROM store WHERE (((store.name) = ('Some')) AND ((strftime("%Y%m%d", datetime(store.created_at,"unixepoch", "localtime"))) >= (strftime("%Y%m%d", datetime(2018-10-12,"unixepoch", "localtime")))))
 2/QueryAll-> []
```

PS. Full disclosure: I'm the current maintainer of SQLObject.

Answer (score 1):

As @phd pointed that SQLObject evaluate the expression before passing it to backend in reducted form.

Then we can also pass expression directly which `SQLObject` will evaluate so instead of passing string literal we can also do as below

```py
def FROM_UNIXTIME(x, y):
    return sqlbuilder.func.strftime("%Y%m%d", sqlbuilder.func.datetime(x, "unixepoch", "localtime"))
```

**Output:**

```py
SELECT store.sample FROM store WHERE (((store.name) = ('Some')) AND ((strftime("%Y%m%d", datetime(store.created_at,"unixepoch", "localtime"))) >= (strftime("%Y%m%d", datetime(2018-10-12,"unixepoch", "localtime")))))
```